# How to get three measures in a single chart?

Tags: tableau-api

I want three measures in a single chart.

1. Time spent by an employee in the office. (Available hours)
2. Time spent by an employee on productive tools. (Productive Hours)
3. Percentage of time spent productively. (PH : AH %)

I have used dual axis for 1 and 2 as 2 will always be less than 1.

[image]

I want it to look something like this[image]

The problem is when I use blended axis it does not show the "tools hours" as a part of "available hours". So for example if an employee was available for 5 hours out of which he worked on productive tools for 3 hours the blended axis will show total available hours to be 8.

Answer (score 0):

Your available hours is aways greater than your tools hours?

So, you should use a calculated Field where you show the tools hours and the "available hours" - tool hours.

It can also be solver by transforming your data source input.

PS: Yes, you can make formulas (calculated fields) across joins and blendings.